# Как узнать первичный ключ EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework

Такая ситуация, создаю объект класса Administrator, и параллельно с ним объект класса User, в котором username и password хранятся, и так же role хранится. Мне так же нужно сохранить в поле PersonId класса User значение поля Id класса Administrator. А как мне узнать поле Id, если его значения сохраняются только после изменения БД. Заново искать этого администратора и брать у него значение Id, или можно как то по другому?
Код метода

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<GetAdminDto>> RegisterAdmin(RegisterAdminDto request)
{
    var response = new ServiceResponse<GetAdminDto>();
    try
    {
        var newAdmin = _mapper.Map<Administrator>(request);
        _context.Administrators.Add(newAdmin);

        var newUser = _mapper.Map<User>(request);
        newUser.Role = "Administrator";
        newUser.PersonId = newAdmin.Id;
        _context.Users.Add(newUser);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        response.Data = _mapper.Map<GetAdminDto>(newAdmin);
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.Success = false;
        response.Data = null;
        response.Message = ex.Message;
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы можете оперировать навигационными свойствами, а не только обычными ID'ами. Т.е. сделайте так: `var newAdmin = ....; newUser.Person = newAdmin;`. Соответственно у вас должно быть навигационное свойство Person.

Comment: @OwDafuq а что если таких ролей больше? То есть не только admin, но и client и coach? Для них так же создать свойства в модели User, и при заполнении 2 из 3 полей оставлять с null?

Comment: Первая мысль: помочь. Но... вижу в коде автомаппер. Тут уже ничем не поможешь, проект обречён. :(

Comment: Или навигационные свойства - после `SaveChanges` айдишники будут получены из БД. Или использовать GUID'ы в качестве id - их можно задавать на клиенте. Есть ещё вариант с HiLo - информация легко гуглится, EF поддерживает.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а что не так с автомаппером?

Comment: С автомаппером приходится писать больше кода, чем без него. Утилита, призванная облегчать жизнь, на самом деле усложняет её. Но это моя личная неприязнь. Большинство как раз любят автомаппер за это: можно наколбасить тысячи строк маппинга. Это выгодно в конторах, где работоспособность разрабов оценивают по количеству строк кода.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну не знаю, я особо много проектов не писал, у меня он наоборот уменьшает количество кода. Вместо написания во всех методах соответствие между моделями БД и ДТО, где сколько свойств, столько и строк, лучше написать одну) Но это мое видение, у вас опыта больше, значит вам виднее…

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю, что Вам нужно добавить

```
_context.SaveChanges()
```

После строки

```
_context.Administrators.Add(newAdmin);
```

По дефолту если добавление администратора произойдет без ошибок, то newAdmin.Id получит значение.